# Create a new user for web application

Tags: asp.net

I'm a C# ASP.NET beginner. I have a question ...

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

      <authorization>
          <allow users="domain/users,...." />
          <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
```

With the code above, The web application can only be accessed by users in "allow users" block.  If we want to add a new user into this list we have to go to web.Config file to add them. Is there a better way to add a new user into "allow users" list ?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're configuring security for a local intranet site (since you're specifying domain users)? In Visual Studio you could use Project -> ASP.NET Configuration, Security tab, and choose Integrated Microsoft Windows authentication (From a local network). Then you can set specific permissions directly on the files/folders of the site in Windows (on the web server). You wouldn't have to change anything in the Web.config in order to add/remove permissions. In this way you can take advantage of Active Directory security groups in the same way that you would manage permissions on a shared folder.